# dc:Creator string literal vs. regex FILTER in SPARQL

Tags: regex, filter, sparql, dublin-core, europeana-api

I am using [Europeana's Virtuoso SPARQL Endpoint](http://sparql.europeana.eu/).

I have been trying to search in SPARQL for content about a specific contributor. To my understanding, this could be carried out this way:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?title 
WHERE {
     ?objectInfo dc:title ?title .
     ?objectInfo dc:creator 'Picasso' .

}
```

Nevertheless, I get nothing in return.

Alternatively, I used **FILTER regex** to search for the literal.

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?title ?creator
WHERE {
     ?objectInfo dc:title ?title .
     ?objectInfo dc:creator ?creator .
     FILTER regex(?creator, 'Picasso')
}
```

This actually worked very well and returned correctly the results.

My question is:  Is it possible to produce the SPARQL query without using **FILTER** to search the work of a particular artist?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what endpoint you're querying?  My first guess is that you need to specify a datatype for the string literal 'Picasso'.  Also, it doesn't look like there's any relation between the two triple patterns in your first query.

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like there is any relation (shared variables) between the two triple patterns in your first query.

Comment: Thank you. I have just updated the info:
I am using Europeana's Virtuoso Endpoint : http://sparql.europeana.eu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there are any objects with 'Picasso' literally as the creator.  **So a regex filter is a good choice, but slow.**

Here's a way to find the strings your regex is matching:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?creator, (count(?creator) as ?ccount)
WHERE {
     ?objectInfo dc:title ?title .
     ?objectInfo dc:creator ?creator .
     FILTER regex(?creator, 'Picasso')
}
group by ?creator
order by ?ccount
```

It might have been easier for you to see that if your had displayed all variables in the select statement:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
     ?objectInfo dc:title ?title .
     ?objectInfo dc:creator ?creator .
     FILTER regex(?creator, 'Picasso')
}
```

If you don't want to use a regex filter, you could enumerate all of the Picasso variants you are looking for:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
         values ?creator { "Picasso, Pablo" "Pablo Picasso" } .
         ?objectInfo dc:title ?title .
         ?objectInfo dc:creator ?creator
    }
```

bif:contains works on this endpoint and is pretty fast:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
     ?objectInfo dc:title ?title .
     ?objectInfo dc:creator ?creator .
     ?creator bif:contains 'Picasso'
     #FILTER regex(?creator, 'Picasso')
}
```

Comment: I don't think `bif:contains` is needed here; the standard includes [**contains**](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains).

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Would you say that using `values` will work faster than `regex`?

Comment: Yes, I would expect `VALUES {}`  to be faster than `FILTER regex()`.  But don't take my word for it...  timing your own queries is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your first query has unconnected triple patterns.

2) I guess and according to [the vocabulary description](http://dublincore.org/documents/dces/), `dc:creator` expects a resource, i.e. a URI. Using the URI of the entity Picasso doesn't work?

```
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Term Name: creator |                                                                                                                                                |
| URI:               | http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator                                                                                                        |
| Label:             | Creator                                                                                                                                        |
| Definition:        | An entity primarily responsible for making the resource.                                                                                       |
| Comment:           | Examples of a Creator include a person, an organization, or a service. Typically, the name of a Creator should be used to indicate the entity. |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It would good to see your data in order to decide whether FILTER on literals is necessary or not.